# How to make Div appear after 5 seconds javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fade

So I created a Div and it will function as a button, I want it to remain invisible until 5 seconds have passed, then I would like the div to fade in. I have the code below but it doesn't work, any help?

Thanks!

Code:

Div ID for the button html:

```
<div id="button" onclick="window.open('home.html','home');" style="cursor: hand;">
```

Script:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$("#button").delay(2000).fadeIn(500);
});
</script>
```

html:

```
<title>Welcome to DayZ</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://dayzgame.com/assets/img/favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fadein.css">


<script src="scripts/fadein.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
$("#button").delay(5000).fadeIn(500);
});
</script>
```

Note: The above is just a snippet from my html file, not the full code.

Answer (score 2):

```
//cache your selector
$button = $('button');

$button.hide();

var timeOut = setTimeout(function() {

    $button.fadeIn();

}, 5000);
```

That method hides the `button` on page load using JavaScript, and then uses a setTimeout object to cause it to wait 5 seconds before fading in (remember to cache your selectors for performance reasons,  as well.)

For the sake of unobtrusive scripting,  you might consider just using a simple CSS `display: none` instead of the `hide()` method.

For the sake of semantic HTML, I switched your `#button` to a `button` element, since your `div` looks and acts like a `button` element; either way the code will work, though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the button to invisible before hand.

The style should be `display:none` or you can do an instant `.fadeOut()` (or `.hide()` as the other answer suggests) with duration 0, then the delay, then the fade in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide the div initially. display: none should needs to be an inline style:

```
<div id="button" onclick="window.open('home.html','home');" style="cursor: hand; display: none;">
```

Script:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#button").delay(5000).fadeIn(500);
});
</script>
```

Jquery delay is expressed in milliseconds, therefore change the delay parameter to 5000.

Comment: I have added the display:none method and now the div remains invisible and does not appear at all. I'll add the html code above